# Using the material ui framework library icons locally

Tags: css, google-material-icons

Can't use the material CSS fonts locally

Have tried downloading the icons but can't seem to find a wat to use am em locally

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your html in the `<head`> tag: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.css">`

Check this site out for more info: 
https://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-iconic-font/

Hope this helps!